# How to get oauth token on reload firebase web app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-api-client

Ok, my english isn't too good, so I will try to be clearliest possible.

I have an app that use firebase authentication with GoogleAuthProvider

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
```

It works fine, I got oauth token and works very good. the session keep alive for anytime wath I may need; recently, I decide implement an API that needs an oauth token and I don't have any problem. Then, the trouble, when I reload/close/reopen/oauth token life timesout, the page/app, I'm already logged in but don't have a valid oauth token.

Firebase authentication doesn't provide any method to refresh or get the token again(I'm not sure).

Have I to use any other API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Auth doesn't provide a mechanism for refreshing OAuth credentials for Google or other social login providers. This is possible, however, using the [Google Sign-In JS](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in).

You can use the Google Sign-In library to sign the user in and obtain OAuth tokens, and then use [`signInWithCredential()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#signinwithcredential) to authenticate with Firebase Auth.

Comment: Very good idea, I don't know how I don't thought it before... a last little bit stupid ask; the client_secret must be secret? can I put it on client side? thanks for your help

Comment: forget it, I've seen the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395694/oauth-2-0-does-the-client-secret-has-to-be-secret